# Using @ModelAttribute in spring hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Getting error while using @ModelAttribute, tried many of the solutions but could not find any answers

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAddUser(
        @RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("role") Role role,
        @RequestParam("email_address") String emailAddress
        ) {
    System.out.println("Inside postAddUser");
    User user = new User(name, role,emailAddress);
    user = userRepository.save(user);
    return "redirect:user?id=" + user.getId();
}
```

My view page is:

```
<title>Add User</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Add User</h2>
                    <form action="user" method="post" role="form">


                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label for="user">User Name:</label> 
                            <input type="text"
                                class="form-control" name="name" id="name"
                                placeholder="Enter User Name" required>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email Address:</label> <input type="email"
                                name="email_address" class="form-control" id="email"
                                placeholder="Enter email Address" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="role">Role:</label> 
                            <select name="role"
                                class="form-control" id="role" placeholder="Enter Role" required>
                                <option disabled selected></option>
                                <c:forEach var="role" items="${roles}">
                                    <option value="${role.value}">${role.name}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="add"
                            class="btn btn-info active">Submit</button>
                        <a href="adminHome" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Back</a>

                    </form>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

User Bean

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="ROLE")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS", nullable = false)
    private String emailAddress;

    public User(){}



    public User(String name, Role role, String emailAddress) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }



}
```

I tried using @ModelAttribute in my controller but somehow value for email is null in when it comes to controller side.

Below is code for same after changing my code to fit @ModelAttribute.

Controller side.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postAddUser(@ModelAttribute("user")User user) {
        System.out.println("Inside postAddUser");
        System.out.println(user.getId());
        System.out.println(user.getEmailAddress());
        System.out.println(user.getName());
        System.out.println(user.getRole());
        user = userRepository.save(user);
        return "redirect:user?id=" + user.getId();
    }
```

View page

```
<title>Add User</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Add User</h2>
                    <form action="user" method="post" role="form">


                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label for="user">User Name:</label> 
                            <input type="text"
                                class="form-control" name="name" id="name"
                                placeholder="Enter User Name" value="${user.name}" required>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email Address:</label> <input type="email"
                                name="email_address" class="form-control" id="email"
                                placeholder="Enter email Address" value="${user.emailAddress}" value="${role.value}" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="role">Role:</label> 
                            <select name="role"
                                class="form-control" id="role" placeholder="Enter Role" required>
                                <option disabled selected></option>
                                <c:forEach var="role" items="${roles}">
                                    <option value="${role.value}">${role.name}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="add"
                            class="btn btn-info active">Submit</button>
                        <a href="adminHome" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Back</a>

                    </form>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
Inside postAddUser
0
null
Harding Berg
HEAD_OF_DEPARTMENT
Mar 10, 2016 2:49:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10097 table: USER column: 
EMAIL_ADDRESS
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceRowConstraints(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertRowSet(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementHandle.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHa
ndler.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2870)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3381)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:884)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:888)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:879)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEnt
ityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.merge(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityMan
agerCreator.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:329)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMe
thodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:368)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(Re
positoryFactorySupport.java:349)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationI
nterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.save(Unknown Source)
    at in.ac.jmi.controllers.AdminController.postAddUser(AdminController.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocab
leHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMapp
ingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHa
ndlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:8
0)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.j
ava:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem with the bellow code :

```
<input type="email" name="email_address" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email Address" value="${user.emailAddress} value="${role.value}" required>
```

You need to use the exact java object field name at your name attribute of input field to map it from view.  So use emailAddress instead of email_address.
I do not understand why you've used two value attributes! Remove value="${role.value}".

Your code should look like this :

```
 <input type="email" name="emailAddress" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email Address" value="${user.emailAddress} required>
```

As you are using spring you can also use spring tag library here. If you use `<form:input path="emailAddress">` it will automatically bind with user object field emailAddress and show the existing field value at form view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@RequestBody`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postAddUser@RequestBody User user) {
```

Comment: Are you saying like this? @RequestMapping(value = "/user", params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String postAddUser @RequestBody(@ModelAttribute("user")User user) {  it says "The annotation @RequestMapping is disallowed for this location"

Comment: Do not use @ModelAttribute.

Only
`public String postAddUser@RequestBody User user) {`

Comment: I am using like this

`@RequestMapping(value = "/addBuyer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Buyer addProductUser(@RequestBody Buyer buyer) throws NullParamException {`

Comment: not working .. can you please share same part of the code i.e. controller and jsp part

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/user", params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    
public String postAddUser(@RequestBody User user) {
       
 System.out.println("Inside postAddUser");

        System.out.println(user.getId());
        System.out.println(user.getEmailAddress());
        System.out.println(user.getName());
        System.out.println(user.getRole());
        user = userRepository.save(user);
        return "redirect:user?id=" + user.getId();
    }`

Comment: It has same results, can you share jsp part of the code. I think something is worng at jsp side

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the email adress to be null use the rignte name liek this

```
<input type="email" name="emailAddress" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email Address" value="${user.emailAddress}" value="${role.value}" required>
```

I suggest you to use the

```
<form:*>
```

tag lib to generate your html

About the @ModelAttribute :

You should also create a method @ModelAttribute("user") otherwise using it only on a parameter of method is useless.

Comment: can you please share the example here..I am new in spring

Comment: look here :
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods